# Apprise: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:8000)

Tags: c#, containers, connection

My apprise container running on 8000 port. When I try to send an Http Request Im facing below error message

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:8000)

I tried to  send an http request to apprise, it gives "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:8000)" error message